# How can I cross platform with Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created an app in both Android & IOS.  I am on the last hurdle of the app.  I was able to get Android user working with IOS user whereas the IOS had a tableview.

Now I am faced with a different problem.  If the "rider" on the iOS app is requesting a ride and the Android driver is available - how can I finish this use case?

If the iOS user makes a request, this is the process:

```
func requestPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("... requestPressed")

    let dict = selectedPin!.addressDictionary
    if dict?.count == 0 {
        // this isn't shown to the user, just in your debug window
        print("no addresses available, try again in a few seconds")
        return
    }
    
    destAddress = selectedPin!.addressDictionary!["Street"] as? String ?? "None"
    if destAddress == "None" {
        print("no valid address available, try again in a few seconds")
        return
    }
    
    if userLocation != nil {
        print("my userLocation: \(userLocation!)")
        if canRequestRyde { // if true ...

            // get the destination area name, and the price
            areaNameDestination = DriveHandler.Instance.getAreaName(latitude: destLat, longitude: destLong)
            print("destination area \(areaNameDestination)")

            requestFarePrice()
            
            rRideHandler.Instance.requestRide(latitude: Double(userLocation!.latitude), longitude: Double(userLocation!.longitude), destLat: Double(destLat), destLong: Double(destLong), currentAddress: self.currentAddress, destAddress: destAddress, farePrice: farePrice)
            
            // reset the driver message
            driverMessage = ""
            
            canRequestRide(delegateCalled: true, request: nil)
            
        } else {

            riderCancelled()
        }
        
    }

}
```

The Firebase entry would look like this:

[image: RideRequests/IOS]

What I need to do from this is for the online Android Driver to either accept/decline the request and follow the steps as if it was Android Rider vs Android Driver.

Below are the steps if Android requests a ride and press "Request" btn:

```
private void requestPickupHere(String uid) {

        Log.e(TAG, "requestPickupHere");

        DatabaseReference dbRequest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common
                .request_tbl); // "RideRequests"

        GeoFire mGeoFire = new GeoFire(dbRequest);
        mGeoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude(),
                Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

        // write to db
        if (search_bar_destination != null) {
            dbRequest.child(uid).child("destination").setValue(search_bar_destination);


        } else if (tap_on_map_destination != null) {
            dbRequest.child(uid).child("destination").setValue(tap_on_map_destination);
        }

        dbRequest.child(riderId).child("status").setValue(""); 

        if (mUserMarker.isVisible()) {
            mUserMarker.remove();
        }

        // Add a new marker
        mUserMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Pickup Here")
                .snippet("")
                .position(new LatLng(Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude(), Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

        mUserMarker.showInfoWindow();

        btnRequest.setText("Getting your DRIVER ...");

        location = getCompleteAddressString(Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude(), Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        Log.e(TAG, "riders location = " + location);

        findDriver();
}
```

When the above code is run, it open an activity "Customer Call" located within the Driver Application, where the driver can either Accept / Deny the request.

How can I get the request to be sent from IOS Rider to the Android Driver in the same way it would work for Android to Android?

Comment: you added both android and ios app for the same project from project setting?

Comment: In firebase yes

Comment: so if you are sharing the same database, there won't be any problem, no matter what platform you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using different platforms shouldn't be an issue, when a user requests a ride then you can add an attribute under the driver in the database for example:

```
DriverRides
       DriverId
            Name: peter
            purpose: needs a ride
```

Then you can retrieve all the requests to be appear for that driver in a `recyclerview`. It shouldn't matter what phone the user is using, except if you want the android user to take requests and the ios user to send requests.

---

You are using the same database for both platforms, so when an ios user or android user store data it will go to the same place. For example if user x uses an iPhone and user y uses a Samsung, you would do the following in the database:

```
Users
  UserId1
     name: userx
     age: 100
  UserId2
     name: usery
     age: 120
```

Comment: I am trying to allow both the ios and android users to be both be riders or drivers. I have android rider to ios driver working, Ios to ios working, android to andtoid working but now with the the code i included, not sure how to get ios rider to android driver working

Comment: As Sam said in the comment above and as I said in my answer, you are using a database I'm not sure why you are differentiating between different platforms and making more work than usual. It shouldn't be a problem both the ios and the android user can store data in the same database, there shouldn't be a platform issue..

Comment: This is my first app so i didnt know how to cross platform. Not sure how to do the way that Sam said. Any examples or howtos would be greatly appreciated

Comment: When my ios rider requests a ride, the android driver is online but not getting the request

Comment: Use `addValueEventListener` instead of `addListenerforSingleValueEvent`

Comment: Where do I use addValueEventListener? in the sendRequestToDriver()?

Comment: All the Android code I provided is in the Rider App and if I am sending a request from the IOS app, the Rider App is at no time accessed, just the Driver App.  To be clear, the Rider and Driver ANDROID apps are 2 separate apps.  I only included them in this post to show you how the ANDROID app works, so it really doesn't matter cause in this use-case I don't have any access to the Android Rider App, just the Driver App.  Basically all I need to know is what do I need to do to get the Android Driver to recognize the request from the iOS Rider?